# Extracting facebook groups data with No admin rights

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I need to extract some data from a facebook group for my research. I tried certain approach and tools but nothing works out the way I wanted. I want to extract things like comment, no. of likes per post, post content, date of post etc.I am looking for a R or python script that can automate this process. I followed many tutorial but they seems to be outdated since facebook change its api. I have come to know that facebook has its own api to do data extraction. Please quide me to do this either in R or in Python.

(Remember - I don't have admin rights to grab the data from the group.)

Comment: In case of R: did you look into the package `Rfacebook`?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://analyticsastra.com/complete-guide-facebook-data-mining-using-r/) blog post about `Rfacebook` helpful. Note that if you don't have admin rights for the group then you're probably out of luck unless you just want to access your own data.

Comment: From the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @DavidEbert That is the cocern. No admin right . People are doing it with softwares . Why Can't we do that with simple coding. I know somewhere there is a way. Please help